# Pandas many to one index

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if it is possible to create a many to one index.
Let's say i have keys `['A', 'B']` and I want them all to point
to the same column.

Which would mean:

```
>>> df['A']
>>> df['B']
```

would return the same result.

The only thing I found is the multi index, which
is not exactly what I want e.g.:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = { ('A', 'A'): np.arange(9), ('A', 'B'): np.ones((),) }
>>> pd.DataFrame(data)

   A
   A    B
0  0  1.0
1  1  1.0
2  2  1.0
3  3  1.0
4  4  1.0
5  5  1.0
6  6  1.0
7  7  1.0
8  8  1.0
```

Any ideas on how I could do this? I'd rather not duplicate those columns.

Answer (score 3):

I'd define the mapping and then select the columns of the DataFrame through the map.

```
dmap = {'A': 'A', 'B': 'A'}
df[dmap['B']].to_frame()

   A
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
```

Comment: What? That's possible?

Comment: Well yeah, the dictionary just maps keys to a value (in this case, both 'A' and 'B' to 'A'), and then that value is passed to the dataframe.

Comment: @Nimi if you do not want to using multiple index, I think this is good way for achieve what you need

Comment: Oh now I see. I blacked out there for a minute. The mapping idea is nice.